# No pubspec.yaml file found. in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to build the project from vs code terminal but it just threw an error

[image]

Comment: Can you provide your folder structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the image, there is another folder inside of `flutter-quizstar-master-step`, therefore execute:

```
cd flutter-quizstar-master
```

then

```
flutter build apk
```